# Wrong field in table UsersOrders

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, orm

I'm trying to add some entities using EntityFramework. I need the same model as in image [image]

I created 3 classes:

```
public class UsersOrders : Entity
{
    public int Order_ID { get; set; }
    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
public class User : Entity
{        
    public int User_ID { get; set; }        
    public string Surname { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string Patronymic { get; set; }        
    public string Phone { get; set; }        
    public string Email { get; set; }        
    public string Password { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<UsersOrders> Orders { get; set; }
}
public class Order : Entity
{        
    public int Order_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
    public virtual User User_ID_Courier { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UsersOrders> Users { get; set; }          
}
```

Using FluentAPI trying to set primary keys in my DBContext:

```
builder.Entity<UsersOrders>()
            .HasKey(od => new {od.Order_ID});
```

It works, but why in DB this field "Order_Order_ID" appears? I'm not sure but I really didn't set this field.

[image]

Thanks for any help!

UPD: OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder) 
    {
        //OrderedDishes
        builder.Entity<OrderedDishes>().HasKey(od => new { od.Order_ID, od.Dish_ID, od.Number });
        builder.Entity<OrderedDishes>().HasRequired(od => od.Order).WithMany(od => od.Dishes).HasForeignKey(od => od.Order_ID);
        builder.Entity<OrderedDishes>().HasRequired(od => od.Dish).WithMany(od => od.Orders).HasForeignKey(od => od.Dish_ID);

        //OrderStatus
        builder.Entity<OrderStatus>().HasKey(os => new { os.Order_ID, os.StatusType_ID });
        builder.Entity<OrderStatus>().HasRequired(os => os.Order);
        builder.Entity<OrderStatus>().HasRequired(os => os.StatusType);

        //DishStatus
        builder.Entity<DishStatus>().HasKey(os => new { os.Order_ID, os.Dish_ID, os.Number, os.StatusType_ID });
        builder.Entity<DishStatus>().HasRequired(os => os.OrderedDishes);
        builder.Entity<DishStatus>().HasRequired(os => os.StatusType);

        //user
        builder.Entity<UsersOrders>().HasKey(od => new { od.Order_ID });
        builder.Entity<UsersOrders>().HasRequired(os => os.User);
        builder.Entity<UsersOrders>().HasRequired(os => os.Order);


        //PriceOfDish
        builder.Entity<PriceOfDish>().HasKey(t => new { t.Dish_ID, t.DateTime });
    }
```

Comment: Shwo us the complete implementation of your OnModelCreating method

Comment: `public int Order_ID { get; set; }` - EntityFramework creates id's standardly

Comment: But why two times? I'm not joking, really can't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong field because you rely on the Code First's convention but your are not following it correctly for the `UsersOrders` entity. Assuming that `Id` is the primary key of `User` class then it will look for `UserId` (not `User_Id`) which is not in your `UsersOrders` entity. The same goes for `Order` navigational property in `UsersOrders`.

To fix this you have to follow the convetion by refactoring your `UsersOrders` and use data annotations like this: (If you use this solution you must remoeve configuration for `UsersOrders` entity in your `OnModelCreating` implementation.

```
public class UsersOrders
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Or in your `OnModelCreating` implementation make the following changes for `UsersOrders` entity like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UsersOrders>().HasKey(od => new { od.Order_ID, od.User_ID });
modelBuilder.Entity<UsersOrders>().HasRequired(os => os.User).WithMany(p => p.Orders).HasForeignKey(p => p.User_ID);
modelBuilder.Entity<UsersOrders>().HasRequired(os => os.Order).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(p => p.Order_ID);
```

In the two solutions, note that `UsersOrders` use composite keys using `Order_Id` and `User_Id` not only `Order_ID`.

Comment: I need only one primary key in table UsersOrders and one foreign. How can I solve this? And I tried the second solution but i always got an error: UsersOrders_Order_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'UsersOrders_Order_Source' in relationship 'UsersOrders_Order'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '1'.

Comment: Sorry but i'm didn't understand a bit. What specific entity did you mean?

Comment: I meant the Entity class that all your class derive.

Comment: Logically this is what to do. Because UsersOders  belong to to one User and one Order. Knowing that the primary key must be composite this is why you must have OrderId and UserId. This is the logic. If you don't do it like it in my answer then know that relational model is really really incorrect.

Comment: I'll be very grateful to you if you can check this my project: [testFoodOnlineDB.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90254390/testFoodOnlineDB.zip)

Comment: I checked your project and my previous comment still make sense. UsersOrders is a join table between Users and Orders. Because UsersOrders hasn't a primary key then you must combine two foreign keys from Users and Orders.

Comment: You have the previous error because with my answer because you are using One to Many realtionalship between Order and UsersOrders then foreign key OrderId can't be used as a primary key of UsersOrders.